# Why does Stark have to be in the Iron Man suit at all?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

We've seen on multiple occasions that the Iron Man suit can be completely autonomous or remote (voice) controlled. Why does Tony ever need to risk his life by actually riding in the suit at all? To me, it would seem more strategic if Stark would just hang back and monitor the fight from a distance.